powershell object: Write-Output returns elements of array, but ConvertTo-Html returns array
I'm having trouble understanding the values returned  by Powershell.
I'm trying to query an API and convert the result to a web page as list.
The following actually produces the desired result:
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
| Write-Output
| ConvertTo-Html
| Out-File -FilePath /pathToFile/presentMockdata.html

I piped the query result to Write-Output before ConvertTo-Html, because it's supposed to enumerate the elements of the array, according to here.
However, if I try to save the query result to a variable first, the HTML output is a description of the returned array, rather than of its elements one by one.
$userData =
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
| Write-Output
Write-Host $userData
ConvertTo-Html -InputObject $userData
| Out-File -FilePath /pathToFile/presentMockdata.html

Write-Host enumerates the desired list of users to the console likes so:
@{id=1; name=Leanne Graham; username=Bret; email=Sincere@april.biz; address=; phone=1-770-736-8031 x56442; website=hildegard.org; company=} @{id=2; name=Ervin Howell; username=Antonette; email=Shanna@melissa.tv; address=; phone=010-692-6593 x09125; website=anastasia.net; company=} 

and so on.
The produced HTML file is this again:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Length</th><th>LongLength</th><th>Rank</th><th>SyncRoot</th><th>IsReadOnly</th><th>IsFixedSize</th><th>IsSynchronized</th><th>Count</th></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>10</td><td>1</td><td>System.Object[]</td><td>False</td><td>True</td><td>False</td><td>10</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>

My intuition would be that the output of Write-Host (the contents of $userData) should be exactly the same as the input to ConvertTo-Html (the contents of $userData), but Powershell disagrees.

Why?
How can I get the desired result while storing the query result in a variable first?


remove | Write-Output.

The difference is in the way ConvertTo-Html behaves with piped input vs the -InputObject parameter - e.g. with $x = @(1, 2, 3) | %{ [pscustomobject] @{ "value" = $_ } }, compare the output from  $x | convertto-html; vs convertto-html -inputobject $x - the first outputs a row per item of the input array, the second outputs a row for each property of the input object.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-7.4#notes for the description of this behaviour in the documentation.

@mclayton, well that explains the difference (which, imho is an insane way to make this), but it leaves question 2. open: how can I pipe a variable into a cmdlet?

Remove the pipe to Write-Host and instead set a variable : $results = Invoke-RestMethod ..........

@Bennypr0fane - see $x | convertto-html in my previous comment - that pipes a variable into convertto-html. In your case it would be $userData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users; $userData | ConvertTo-Html...
